# Pytest - Dynamic replacement of functions and test data

Tags: python, pytest

Please help.

I can't reduce these two tests to one with variable data in @ Pytest.mark.parametrize (). I would be very grateful for an explanation of how to do this. I need use @pytest.fixture() or something else.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("sample, exception_type, expected", [
        (lambda: 1, TypeError, "Name must be a string type."),
        (lambda: "", AttributeError, "Title can't be empty."),
        (lambda: '60charactertext' * 4, AttributeError, 'Length name must be shorter than 60 characters.'),
        (lambda: '60charactertext' * 4 + ' ', AttributeError, 'Length name must be shorter than 60 characters.'),
    ])
    def test_rules_for_creating_the_name_of_the_main_window(sample, exception_type, expected):
        with pytest.raises(exception_type) as exc_info:
            rules_for_creating_the_name_of_the_main_window(sample)
        assert exc_info.type is exception_type
        assert str(exc_info.value) == expected
    
    
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("sample, exception_type, expected", (
            (lambda: (1023, 768), RuntimeError, "Lowest supported resolution is: Width: 1024, Height: 768. \n"
                                                "You can change it, but maybe it cause undesirable effects. You need to check the functionality related \n"
                                                "to scale the size of windows "),
    ))
    def test_resctriction_for_minimal_screen_resolution(sample, exception_type, expected):
        with pytest.raises(exception_type) as exc_info:
            resctriction_for_minimal_screen_resolution(sample)
        assert exc_info.type is exception_type
        assert str(exc_info.value) == expected
```

Comment: You could do this by adding the tested function as a parameter, but why would you do this? I would make the tests less readable in my opinion.

Comment: Possible, but the test code repeats only with a different parameter. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: You mean if it is wrong to have duplicated code in the tests? Readability is more important in tests than some duplication. This way you have dedicated tests for dedicated functions. At least for the shown code, this is better IMO.